# How to Vertical align text in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have the following div

```
<div align="left">
            <div  class="about inner" valign="middle" style="height:25px;vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;&nbsp;About
                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div><br>
            <div class="work" style="height:25px;vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Work
                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div><br>
            <div class="contact" style="height:25px;vertical-align: middle;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact
                <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div><br>
        </div>
```

how to align the contents inside (glyphicon as well as the text) each div vertically center?

CSS:

```
.contact{
        color: #edf2d4;
    background: #a2c635;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #a2c635 0%, #d3db6b 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#a2c635), color-stop(100%,#d3db6b));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #a2c635 0%,#d3db6b 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #a2c635 0%,#d3db6b 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #a2c635 0%,#d3db6b 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(left, #a2c635 0%,#d3db6b 100%);
    vertical-align: middle;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a2c635', endColorstr='#d3db6b',GradientType=1 );
}
```

Comment: Can you share your CSS you have created as well?

Comment: Need your explanation that what you exactly needed."How to Vertical align text in div" made the div vertically centre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 solutions:

1- Use `display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle`

2- Use `position:absolute; transform:translateY(-50%);top:50%`

```css
.relative{position:relative;height:300px}
.middle{position:absolute;top:50%;transform:translateY(-50%)}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
<div class="middle">
<h1>Middle</h1>
</div>
</div>
```