# Bootstrap 3 Five column responsive with fixed height and width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a 5 column responsive layout in bootstrap 3 but the box automatically expands based on the content actually i need a fixed width and height for all 5 box so everything stays in the box i tired all code and reference in stackoverflow

And below you can find the HTML & CSS Code

Please check the output of the code in fullpage

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .ten-columns > .col-sm-2 {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
.card-box {
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.widget-box-one .widget-one-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  font-size: 72px !important;
  top: 0;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 2 !important;
}
.widget-box-one .wigdet-one-content {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row ten-columns text-center">

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="card-box widget-box-one">
                            <div class="wigdet-one-content">
                                <p class="m-0 text-uppercase font-600 font-secondary text-overflow">One</p>
                                <img style="width:90px" src="https://i.imgur.com/kspWJKK.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
     
     <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="card-box widget-box-one">
                            <div class="wigdet-one-content">
                                <p class="m-0 text-uppercase font-600 font-secondary text-overflow">Stat</p>
                                <h2 class="text-danger"><span data-plugin="counterup">I am just a dummy text with max 35 characters</span></h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="card-box widget-box-one">
                            <div class="wigdet-one-content">
                                <p class="m-0 text-uppercase font-600 font-secondary text-overflow">SPD</p>
                                <h2 class="text-dark"><span data-plugin="counterup">22</span> </h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="card-box widget-box-one">
                            <div class="wigdet-one-content">
                                <p class="m-0 text-uppercase font-600 font-secondary text-overflow">D-Goal</p>
                                <h2 class="text-success"><span data-plugin="counterup">12</span></h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="card-box widget-box-one">
                            <div class="wigdet-one-content">
                                <p class="m-0 text-uppercase font-600 font-secondary text-overflow">B-Level</p>
                                <img style="width:90px" src="https://i.imgur.com/kspWJKK.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use flex display and set height:100% to .card-box

```
.ten-columns{
/*its like Bootstrap 4*/
display: -webkit-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.ten-columns > .col-sm-2 {
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-ms-flex: 0 0 20%;
flex: 0 0 20%;
max-width: 20%;
}
}
.card-box {
/*add height:100% to .card-box*/
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks how can i make the content center in top and bottom i.e the following text 22, 12 and the image

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138191/how-to-vertical-align-text-in-div/38139065#38139065 I think your answer is here

Comment: thanks for the link but this one worked for me transform:translateY(50%)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. I solved my problem with this

Changed row width to 240%. As in bootstrap row consists of 12 columns, so to fill the same width (of 12 columns) increased the size of row (12/5 = 2.4).

There is a little problem here that the scrollbar is visible but is not visible in my .fluid-container and this can be solved.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  
}
.card-box {
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.widget-box-one .widget-one-icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  font-size: 72px !important;
  top: 0;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 2 !important;
}
.widget-box-one .wigdet-one-content {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row ten-columns text-center" style="width: 240%">

                    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                        <div class="card-box widget-box-one">
                            <div class="wigdet-one-content">
                                <p class="m-0 text-uppercase font-600 font-secondary text-overflow">One</p>
                                <img style="width:90px" src="https://i.imgur.com/kspWJKK.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
     
     <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                        <div class="card-box widget-box-one">
                            <div class="wigdet-one-content">
                                <p class="m-0 text-uppercase font-600 font-secondary text-overflow">Stat</p>
                                <h2 class="text-danger"><span data-plugin="counterup">I am just a dummy text with max 35 characters</span></h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                        <div class="card-box widget-box-one">
                            <div class="wigdet-one-content">
                                <p class="m-0 text-uppercase font-600 font-secondary text-overflow">SPD</p>
                                <h2 class="text-dark"><span data-plugin="counterup">22</span> </h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                        <div class="card-box widget-box-one">
                            <div class="wigdet-one-content">
                                <p class="m-0 text-uppercase font-600 font-secondary text-overflow">D-Goal</p>
                                <h2 class="text-success"><span data-plugin="counterup">12</span></h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                        <div class="card-box widget-box-one">
                            <div class="wigdet-one-content">
                                <p class="m-0 text-uppercase font-600 font-secondary text-overflow">B-Level</p>
                                <img style="width:90px" src="https://i.imgur.com/kspWJKK.png">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var minHeight = parseInt(0);
                $(".tens-columns > div").each(function(){
                    if($(this).outerHeight() > minHeight){
                        minHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
                    }
                });

            $('.tens-columns > div').css('height', minHeight);
            }
```